Why the reference of a variable with external linkage is treated as constant expression
I am new to C++ and I am curious about why the reference of a variable with external linkage is treated as constant expression in the following example:
#include <iostream>
template<decltype(auto) N>
class C {

};

int i;

// not allowed
//C<i> x;

C<(i)> x;

int main()
{
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    int j;
    // not allowed
//    C<(j)> j;
    return 0;
}

In the above example, the type of the non-type template parameter N is int & due to the non-type template argument (i) .

Just guessing: if i is global, a refrence to it (which is similar to a pointer - i.e. its address) can actually be known at compile time. This cannot be said about the value of i.

See this answer in the dupe: Why using the address of the first element of the array as template non-type argument is possible in c++ 17

@wohlstad Thanks, in the case of that answer, the behavior of the program changed from c++17 to c++20 for arrays as mentioned in that answer.

@user12002570 Excuse me, may I ask it is the same question. I am asking why the reference of a variable with external linkage is treated as constant expression rather than what the reference shall not refer to. I read the content in tmp.arg , but I don't know which clause fit my situation.

@fade As I explained in the dupe, when i is global it has static storage duration. On the other hand, j in your code doesn't have static storage duration. You can verify this if you make j static like static int j;. Then the program will start working. See demo. That is why in the dupe's answer I said: "The important thing to note is that a has static storage duration..."

@user12002570 May I ask you why we need static storage duration in such situation and why the reference of a variable with static storage duration is allowed to be used as non-type template argument? I am still quite confused.

@fade Because those variable's address can't change during program.

@fade See this answer where I explained the same. That should make it clear.
